# Can push-in wire connectors handle 20 amp circuits?

Tags: electrical

Can push in connections handle 20 amp circuits?  The box claims that 22 to 12 gauge wire can fit, but little else. Sorry if this is a silly query.

Comment: What actual connector? Picture of the box. Brand and model number. Without that all that can be said is that some push in connections can handle 20A but yours might not.

Answer (score 6):

As long as it is rated for it, it can handle it.  I use these [IDEAL push connectors](https://www.grainger.com/product/5EKL4?cm_re=AZIDPRR&cm_sp=Product_Details-_-Similar_Products-_-AZIDPRR_57295&cm_vc=AZIDPRR_57295) ALL THE TIME.

Comment: I replace those push in connectors all the time. I do not think they should be legal and do believe they are the reason for arc fault requirements. Push in connectors have made me thousands for easy work on my part but IMO give the industry a bad rep.

Answer (score 5):

Push-in connectors such as the Ideals linked in another answer or Wagos are rated for wire size, NOT amperage. If it can accept a #12 wire then it is safe to say it can be used on a 20A circuit.

Answer (score 3):

Many connectors are rated for 20A, If you worry about push-in connectors, try something like this

[image]

> WAGO  222-413  3 Conductor Terminal Block with Levers
>   No. of Positions  3
>   Rated Voltage  600V
>   **Rated Current  20A**
>   Wire Size AWG Min  28AWG
>   Wire Size AWG Max  12AWG
>   Wire Connection Method  Push In Lock

They have a handy guide on the back for insulation trimming.

Just keep your fingers out of the way when releasing the tiny orange levers!

Comment: Those connectors are great for low amperage devices I use them on Flouresents fixtures and have never had one fail in that case and they do sting when closing if it hits your finger nail so a plus for that, I have repaired hundreds of failed back stabs in the U.S. and these were only rated for 15 amps so I would never and do not use any kind of stab connector other than a low wattage fixture would use.

Answer (score 0):

Wago website gives all of the specs but we must think beyond the specs to be on the safe side. Reasons are many beyond the specs, for instance, the 8 or actually listed as 7 terminal although there are 8 holes plus the feed line is rated for 24A however, I wouldn't suggest anyone use them near anything hot such as a light fixture unless there is ample distance. Rated at 60C things can reach hot temps and over the course of say, maybe 10 years or so the plastic will become brittle due to this. Wago is an excellent connection for a box that is not going to have added heat or weathering due to sun or water etc...

I don't care what wire nut heads say Wago has beautiful products and they do work if used correctly and save you a lot of time. Often the problem I find with wire nuts is that far too often people simply don't strip old connections back. If you look at the wiring with oxidization on it yes sure it is copper but over the years as this build up happens there is a loss at this connection. What most folks complain about is having to strip a little casing back or shorten the wires. let me tell you if 6 inches code doesn't get it done for you for the life of your home you should be more than happy you made it to that point! Learn how to work it ;).

Their specs are actually pretty spot on and they meet code there are a lot of naysayers out there but don't listen to them. Do NOT use them around another source of heat and do not exceed 20A and they should last a lifetime! Also, what is the deal with people not educating each other VxA=W simple grade school formula tell them not to exceed the wattage rating of their wire and circuit? Every homeowner should be required to know this information! Instead, we like to keep people in the dark so we can pinch them for all they have where does it end we are talking about someone's life possibly versus dollars. Teach anyone and everyone the basics it should be a requirement in high school actually!

They are excellent connections and they only time I have ever seen them fail was around another heat source, or if someone overloaded the circuit. Know the connector, not all are rated for 24A some are rated for more like the clampdown series but many are rated for way less. In the specs, it will tell you wire size, amperage and more. It will accept #10 wire but why push it just stay with 12 wire and 20A to be safe with the dark grey 8 hole terminal connector. As a general rule anything run at max rating is pushing it best to stay under that a fair amount. They work don't believe the rubbish if people want arthritis and carpal tunnel and want to spend their day twisting away let them you don't have to!!! But be sure to follow the guidelines and specs and look at other data beyond that to make an informed decision you can wire nut your way to the heavens for all I care but I'll use these push in connectors and sleep well at night after 15+ years of doing so.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  This post could use some tidying up, mostly in the area of punctuation.  There is an [edit] button just below your answer text.

Answer (score -2):

Yes they can & do. Although, the only kind of "push connector" you want is a Terminal Block, it's push-in & then screw-down clamping, they're the best of both worlds & come in all shapes, sizes & colors. If it's just push alone, return it & never buy them again. They aren't easily correctable, re-usable, reliable nor long lasting & therefore not trustworthy. That being said though, I've used Wago's just a few times & their locking arm version did seem to be an upgrade to address some of my issues, but those versions aren't "really" push-ins either. I can't yet speak to Wago's reliability nor longevity.

Comment: Have you ever tried to get 12 gauge wire out of an IDEAL push connector?  I wouldn't base your answer on buying cheap products.

Comment: I have not. Can you remove the wires or do you have to cut them free? My first experience with push-ins was a dead outlet. I removed the outlet from the box & the wires slipped right out to stay in the box. The new & improved may be perfectly fine but I won't be switching until I have no other option.

Comment: I am over 200 pounds and ex football player... I looked like a little girl trying to put a piece of wire out of that damn connector after my son put a neutral in with the hots.  The wires were already short so tried not cutting...  took me about 10 mins of twisting.

Comment: That's fantastic, but does it last is my issue. If it's a bendable flap that only moves one-way or a spring tensioned jaw it will fail in maybe just 10-years & be worth or worse. You won't have any such removal, reuse, correcting or fatiguing issue with a push-in & screw-down.

Comment: The question was about push-in connectors, NOT backstabbed receptacles. The connection is similar, but the connectors, such as Ideal's or Wagos, are VASTLY superior. I know this because he is asking about what it says on the box, and that they will accept up to #12. Backstab receptacles will only handle up to #14.

Comment: I'll confirm the ideal quality (not the claim that they're tremendously difficult to remove; work with them for a decade and you'll figure it out). Rotation is their biggest nemesis but IMHO they have their good and bad uses; Good: in a lighting fixture. Bad: in a typical 4x4 jBox.

Comment: Sorry, I consider a backstab a push-in & so does anyone who's ever used or just seen one. Now, Wago's with the locking lever I have no problem with & those can even be taped. As I said, I have not used Ideal's. But, if they're so great, then why don't circuit breakers use them, those are push-in too.

Comment: **_"But, if they're so great, then why don't circuit breakers use them, those are push-in too."_** ......... HUH??

Comment: Hey, if it's so great & so reliable & long lasting...which you attest it's not. I wouldn't use them & I don't use Wago's even. I tried Wago's & they seemed solid, but I'm not in a hurry to do a half-assed job.

Comment: Non-removability sounds like a very unworkable misfeature.  (a stab used a second time is not safe.)  I think what Iggy means is when circuit breakers have push-ins, the grabbing force comes from tightening down a screw, and loosening same screw frees the wire.

Comment: Thanks Wolf. I just don't see the point. Are wire nuts & terminal blocks somehow tedious & taking more than a minute? Why use something that requires wires to be chopped down, has connection issues, can't be reused & may not last? Can you imagine all the Ceiling Fan Questioners here using push-ins, they wouldn't even have wire stubble left in the box.

Comment: **_"Hey, if it's so great & so reliable & long lasting...which you attest it's not."_** ..... Who said they are not??? And no one is saying they are the greatest thing either. They are good and have their place. Will they replace wire nuts? Never IMO. .....Thing is, you are throwing your opinion of these connectors in where it is not needed. The question was simple, are they rated for 20A. You not only did not answer the question, you derailed it.

Comment: "Will they replace wire nuts?" - just FYI: in other parts pf the world, screw-terminal blocks are the standard. Wire-nuts are unheard of (and may not even be legal) while push-ins are rare and usually only found on permanently-installed lighting fixtures.

Comment: They are already replacing wire nuts. They are listed and approved for use.  You can remove wires from Ideal style connectors with a pair of needle nose and some leverage. If you have ever made up several hundred connections over a couple days you would welcome these devices. They are a whole lot easier on your hands and fingers. They also save a lot of time especially if you are a twister. I could probably make up twice as many push-ins compared to twisting and wire nutting. The old-timers probably hated wire nuts when they first came out too. You could go back to soldering if you like.

Comment: There's been a long history in US industry of a step toward convenience taking us a step away from safety.  Anyone with experience has seen wire-nut and backstab failures.  **Caution is not a character flaw**, and the question we ask ourselves is "how can we avert this failure in *our* work"?  Care obviously matters with wire-nuts; but I have *no earthly idea* why stabs fail.  Of course products evolve, but *it's rather telling* that Europe has not permitted the wire-nut, let alone stabs.  Of course I have the luxury of not being a builder doing 500 splices a day on thin margin.

Comment: This is another question with good information on both sides but no OP up vote, we should start purging or protecting these so they do not waste any more of our time in my opinion.